# Dual EPUB reading

Tags: android, ebooks, reading, epub

I have started using my tablet for reading EPUBs and I have found a lot of differents versions of the same book.

So, is there any application that allows me to compare, i.e., to see both versions in a two-divided screen?

In fact I thought it would be easier to find it because it is such a useful utility! I have tried the 10 most used application for reading EPUBs and no single one allows me to do this.

Comment: For PDFs: [How to read 2 or more documents side-by-side in Android?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/59791/12202)

Comment: For the curious: We've tried to move [the original question](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/77430/16575) over here, but somehow the process got stuck (and the question closed as off-topic). So please bear with Marc and don't blame him for cross-posting :)

Answer (score 3):

<sup>Just for completeness, let me repeat the recommendation [I gave on Android.SE](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/77472/16575):</sup>

There's **EPUB3 Reader** available on [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=it.angrydroids.epub3reader) and [Github](https://github.com/pettarin/epub3reader) (not on *Google Play* – though an app using the same package name exists there, it's not the same, but obviously based on the original developers engine; long story behind that, not fitting here). Its app description explicitely mentions this feature:

> - parallel texts (e.g., original text and its translation into another language).

Find [some screenshots here](https://github.com/pettarin/epub3reader/blob/master/SCREENSHOTS.md). Picking one example:

[image: EPUB3 Reader]

Looks exactly like what you're after.